# google app engine _method?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

How can I get the request body passed on to my views?

```
class RestHTTPMiddleware(object):
  def __init__(self, app):
    self.app = app

  def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
    request = Request(environ)
    environ['wsgi.input'] = StringIO.StringIO(request.body)

    method = webapp.Request(environ).get('_method')

    if method:
      environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] = method.upper()

    return self.app(environ, start_response)
```

when i test :

```
def put(self):
    logging.info("spot put %s", self.request.get("name"))
```

the following is logged: "spot put" but with no value.

this is how it's implemented:

```
def main():  
  app = webapp.WSGIApplication([
    (r'/spot/new/$', Spot),
    ],
   debug=True)
  # run_wsgi_app(application)
  wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler().run(RestHTTPMiddleware(app))
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Why not just access self.request.body?

Comment: I want to be able to use put() and delete() methods in webapp, one way to do so is by using the <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put|delete|" /> in forms

Comment: If it's input[type=hidden], it means you are setting it's value in code. Set the appropriate method as `<form method="...">` instead.

Comment: You cannot use method="put" or method="delete" since browsers do not support it, it simply changes to a default method="get" when the form i submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there with this code, I think. Did you try and see if it works if you run `fp.seek(0)` after the Request instance is created?

I should also note that **this is a dangerous hack!** This allows me to trick your Web server into believing that an `<img src="http://yourserver.com/?_method=POST&delete_account=1">` is a legitimate POST request from the user who views my site. Plainly: this is dangerous out of security perspective. **Do not do this unless you feel certain you have other mechanisms that counteract this Pandora's box of CSRF nightmares.**